# Can we visit each block of 4*4 exactly once?

Tags: geometry

> A person is standing at a corner of $4\times4$ square, he would like to travel each block exactly once before exiting from the opposite corner. Is there a way?

Comment: Move diagonally.

Comment: Or use a Knight's move!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

> NO

Explanation:

> Colour each cell black or white like a checker board and suppose the starting point is black. Then the ending point is black. S means starting point and E means ending point.
> [image: 1]
> That person has to walk $4^2-1$ times, so that person must end at a white cell. Not a black cell.

Answer (score 2):

Well,

> Some lateral thinking gets the job done:
> [image: Solution]